# python numberguessing game

Tags: python, function-call

i was working on a guessing game in python and its almost complete. but the bug is that it keeps checkng the condition from the first user input even though I've reassigned the initial variable to a new user input. pls what can i do to fix it?

```
import random

number = random.randint(1,101)

print(f"the no is {number}")

def check(user_guess):
    global level
    global game_over 
    if level <= 0:
        print("you ran out of guesses...")
        return False
    if user_guess > number:
        print("too high")
        level -= 1
        print(f"guesses left: {level}")
        user_guess = int(input("guess again "))
        game_over  = False
    elif user_guess < number:
        print("too low")
        level -= 1
        print(f"guesses left: {level}")
        user_guess = int(input("guess again "))
    elif user_guess == number:
        print("you guessed right")
        return False
    



level = 0


def levels():
    '''assigns the level to the user'''
    global game_over
    global level
    print("Welcome to the number guessing game...")
    difficulty = input("enter a difficulty: Easy or Hard? ").lower()
    if difficulty == 'easy':
        level = 10
        print(f"guesses: {level}")
    elif difficulty == 'hard':
        level = 5
        print(f"guesses : {level}")
    else:
        print("error")
        


game_over = False

levels()
user_guess = int(input("make a guess "))

while not game_over:
    check(user_guess)
    if check(user_guess) == False:
        game_over = True
```

this is the entire code
ive tried calling the check function in different places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this chunk of code:

```py
user_guess = int(input("make a guess "))

while not game_over:
    check(user_guess)
    if check(user_guess) == False:
        game_over = True
```

Your code asks for an input, then makes it an int, storing it in the variable user_guess. Then, you use your check function to check the variable. However, you do not ask for an input again!

Think about it this way. If I input `3`, the user_guess variable is set as the number 3 and never changed again.

To fix this issue, put the `user_guess = int(input("make a guess "))` bit right before the check() function.

```py
while not game_over:
    user_guess = int(input("make a guess "))
    check(user_guess)
    if check(user_guess) == False:
        game_over = True
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue with your code is that you're not updating the user guess inside the while loop. You are passing the same user guess to the check function every time, even after the user has guessed again.

If I may suggest one solution would be to try and move the line that takes the user's guess inside the while loop, so that it's updated with each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the user input inside while loop.

```
while not game_over:
    user_guess = int(input("make a guess "))
    check(user_guess)
    if check(user_guess) == False:
        game_over = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I've just remade it for you much simpler I think but hope this helps

```
import random
import sys

number = random.randint(1, 100)
print(number)

def hard():
    print("Enter a numbr between 1 and 100")
    guesses = 5
    while True:
        print(f"You have {guesses} guesses left")
        guess = int(input("Enter a number : "))
        if guesses == 0:
            again = input("game over!\nTry again ? ").upper()
            if 'YES' in again:
                level()
            else:
                print("goodbye")
                break
        
        elif guess > 100 or guess < 0:
            print("Please only numbers between 1 and 100")

        elif guess < number:
            print("guess is too low try again")
            guesses = guesses - 1

        elif guess > number:
            print("guess is too high try again")
            guesses = guesses - 1

        else:
            again = input("Well done correct\nTry again ? ").upper()
            if 'YES' in again:
                level()
            else:
                print("goodbye")
                break
                
                    
        

def level():
    print("""
Enter a level Easy or Hard
    """)
    while True:
        chosen_level = input(">").upper()
        if chosen_level == "HARD":
            hard()
        elif chosen_level == "EASY":
            easy()
        else:
            print("Invalid option")
    
def easy():
    print("Enter a numbr between 1 and 100")
    guesses = 10
    while True:
        print(f"You have {guesses} guesses left")
        guesses = int(input("Enter a number : "))
        if guess == 0:
            again = input("game over!\nTry again ? ").upper()
            if 'YES' in again:
                level()
            else:
                print("goodbye")
                break
        
        elif guess > 100 or guess < 0:
            print("Please only numbers between 1 and 100")

        elif guess < number:
            print("guess is too low try again")
            guesses = guesses - 1

        elif guess > number:
            print("guess is too high try again")
            guesses = guesses - 1

        else:
            again = input("Well done correct\nTry again ? ").upper()
            if again == "YES":
                level()
            else:
                print("goodbye")
                break
          
level()
```

Comment: You should try to explain what their problem was. Don't just fix it for them, because the goal of stack overflow is to create Q&As that can be referred back to if someone else later has the same question.

Answer (score 0):

You had multiple problems with your code, including asking for the users input twice, once outside `check()` and once inside `check()`.

Not to mention, your code was super unreadable, which made it harder to figure out the issue.

```py
while not game_over:
    # Here is your problem. You are checking the users guess and then checking their new one.
    # However the value of user_guess is not being changed
    check(user_guess)
    print(user_guess)
    if check(user_guess) == False:
        game_over = True
```

I ran an example where the number was `22`. I first guessed `21`, and it said it was too low. When it asked me to guess again, I said `23`. After that, the print statement ran; however, it printed `21`. This showed that the `user_guess` was not being updated.

Below, I've fixed and improved your code in regards to "the bug" and readability

```py
import random

def check(user_guess, guesses):
    '''Checks if the users guess was correct.
    Otherwise, gives feedback on whether it was too high or too low'''
    if guesses <= 1:
        print("you ran out of guesses...")
        exit(0)
    if user_guess > number:
        print("too high")
        guesses -= 1
        print(f"guesses left: {guesses}")
    elif user_guess < number:
        print("too low")
        guesses -= 1
        print(f"guesses left: {guesses}")
    elif user_guess == number:
        print("you guessed right")
        exit(0)
    
    return guesses

def get_input(text: str):
    '''Gets input from the user, and attempts to convert it to an integer.
    Exits the program if it fails.'''
    try:
        return int(input(text))
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid number")
        exit(0)

def levels():
    '''assigns the level to the user.
    Returns the amount of guesses the user gets based on the level they chose.'''
    
    print("Welcome to the number guessing game...")
    difficulty = input("enter a difficulty: Easy or Hard? ").lower()
    if difficulty == 'easy':
        guesses = 10
        print(f"guesses: {guesses}")
    elif difficulty == 'hard':
        guesses = 5
        print(f"guesses : {guesses}")
    else:
        print("error")
        exit(0)
    return guesses
        


if __name__ == '__main__': # Easy way to tell the reader where to start reading the program
    number = random.randint(1,101)
    guesses = levels()

    print(f"the no is {number}")

    while True:
        guesses = check(get_input("Make a guess: "), guesses)
```